# Trying to change classes on button click

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to do a simple animation where an image changes from A to B to C on the click of a button. I'm getting stuck at `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')`, but I can't figure out what I did wrong; I used a similar structure for a carousel without any issues.

I'm just trying to change the elements from "seed" to Bootstrap's ".d-none".

```js
var javaButton = document.getElementById("button-trigger");

const track = document.querySelector(".plant-wrapper");
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
const targetIndex = slides.findIndex;
const hidden = document.querySelector(".d-none");
const seeds = document.querySelector(".seed");

javaButton.addEventListener("click", moveToSlide);

function moveToSlide(slides, seeds, hidden, targetIndex) {
  if (targetIndex === 0) {
    seeds.classList.add("is-hidden");
    hidden.classList.remove("is-hidden");
  } else if (targetIndex === slides.length - 1) {
    seeds.classList.remove("is-hidden");
    hidden.classList.add("is-hidden");
  } else {
    seeds.classList.remove("is-hidden");
    hidden.classList.remove("is-hidden");
  }
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button-trigger">Check it out!</button>
<div class="plant-wrapper">
  <img src="images/seed.png" class="seed mx-auto d-block" id="seed1">
  <img src="images/sprout.png" class="mx-auto d-block d-none" id="seed2">
  <img src="images/stem.png" class="mx-auto d-block d-none" id="seed3">
  <img src="images/pot.png" class="pot mx-auto d-block">
</div>
```

Comment: `seeds` is undefined; because the only thing you're passing to the function is a reference to the Event Object, and nothing else. Also, what is `const targetIndex = slides.findIndex;`? [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is a function, that expects an argument.

Comment: what's this suppose to do:  const slides = Array.from(track.children);

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you do not pass arguments to `moveToSlide` function

You can solve removing arguments of `moveToSlide` function (function will read variables declared above)

```js
function moveToSlide() {
  // Code...
}
```

Or passing values to function (best option)

```js
javaButton.addEventListener("click", () => moveToSlide(slides, seeds, hidden, targetIndex))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I applied your solution and the error goes away, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to create a slider, there's a better way to do it.

w3schools have a demo of it: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Here is my way to make a slider:

index.html

```
<button type="button" id="button-trigger" onclick="changeImg()">Check it out!</button>

<div class="plant-wrapper" id="plant-wrapper">
</div>
```

index.js

```
var index = 0;

const imageArray = [
    "images/1.png",
    "images/2.png",
    "images/3.png",
    "images/4.png"
];

function changeImg(){
    (index == imageArray.length - 1 ? index = 0 : index++);
    showImage();
}

function showImage(){
    document.getElementById("plant-wrapper").innerHTML = '<img src="' + imageArray[index] + '" class="mx-auto" />';
}   

window.onload = function() {
    showImage()
}
```